# can't access Nexus Sonatype from another machine within a LAN

Tags: maven, networking, webserver, nexus, sonatype

I have two Ubuntu 12.04 machines connected with a crossover cable. I manually configured the IP to be 1.1.1.0 and 1.1.1.1. I can do `ping`, `rcp` and use `git clone` no problem between the two machines. I also have Nexus Sonatype configured in 1.1.1.0 and try to have the other machine to pull dependencies from that one but doesn't work I get "can't establish connection" I get the same error trying to access the Nexus Sonatype web server from that machine.

My Nexus Sonatype process looks like this:

```
azg       4102  4100  1 19:21 ?        00:00:29 java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol=plain ssl -Djava.library.path=bin/jsw/lib -classpath bin/jsw/lib/wrapper-3.2.3.jar:./lib/sisu-jetty8-1.4.2.jar:./lib/logback-classic-1.0.7.jar:./lib/appcontext-3.2.jar:./lib/jetty-security-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/metrics-jetty-2.2.0.jar:./lib/metrics-logback-2.2.0.jar:./lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:./lib/jetty-util-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/jetty-deploy-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/nexus-logging-extras-appender-2.5.1-01.jar:./lib/nexus-bootstrap-2.5.1-01.jar:./lib/jetty-xml-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:./lib/jetty-server-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/jetty-continuation-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/jetty-servlet-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/jetty-webapp-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/jetty-http-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/jetty-jmx-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:./lib/jetty-io-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/logback-core-1.0.7.jar:./lib/jetty-rewrite-8.1.8.v20121106.jar:./lib/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar:./conf/ -Dwrapper.key=lOc_daTBExiskDCG -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=4100 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jsw.JswLauncher ./conf/jetty.xml
```

Netstat produces the following output:

```
azg@olympus:~$ sudo netstat -anp | grep ":80.*LISTEN"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4102/java
```

Can anyone shed light into what's wrong here?

UPDATE: [This other question](https://superuser.com/questions/643525/two-network-configurations-in-linux) may be related to this issue i.e. using an incorrect ip range. I have to test this tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local private network is reserved the range 192.168.x.x.
The adresses: 192.168.0.0 and 192.168.0.255 you should not use.
The Ips 1.1.1.0 and 1.1.1.1 are internet adresses and used in Australia, this is a Class A netwok and can be used for 16.777.214 hosts in 128 networks.

If you set up a home network then use 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 and so on, try to stay in a Class C network, use for 254 hosts with a mask of 255.255.255.0.

PS. 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 and 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 are also private netwoks and not used in the internet

I am reading "direct cable between the two boxes" ? I think you need a special cable, the normal network cable working only if you connect the two boxes with each other over a switch or hub.

Comment: Thank you, this might be connected to the issue then. The reason why I don't use the "Class C" network is because it is already in use by a Wireless adapter and I have no control on the Wireless router that assigns via DNS Class C network ip addresses. Check the UPDATE I just posted.

Comment: Indeed this solved the issue. The problem was the IP misconfiguration.